# Sendgrid remove unsubscribe per API

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

When a user gets a mail from me, there is an unsubscribe link. If he goes to that link, then he is unsubscribed and goes to my unsubcribe group. This all works, but how can I remove the unsubscribe maybe he want to undo. Is there an API where I can remove the unsubscribe by the email or how can I do this?